# adding weighted mse loss function in keras

Tags: tensorflow

I built a weighted mse loss function in Keras, all according to the documentation. However, the weights "Pz" are an additional input to the model, and totally unrelated to the other inputs. Somehow I can't figure out how to pass that to the fit command

```
def weighted_mse(weight):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        tmp = K.square(y_true-y_pred)
        return K.sum(tmp*weight) / K.sum(weight)
    return loss


model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(nbin*2, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, nbin)))
model.add(Dense(nbin*2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(nbin))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

Pz = Input(shape=(nbin,))
model.compile(loss=weighted_mse(Pz), optimizer='adam')

model.fit([p_evd, Pz], p_opt, batch_size=nfram)
```

This code gives the following error during compilation:

> ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays
>   that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected.
>   Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 2
>   arrays: [array([[[3.299e-01, 1.782e-01, 4.603e-02, ..., 1.454e-02,
>   6.400e-03, 2.321e-03],
>           [5.506e-01, 2.307e-01, 1.520e-02, ..., 1.874e-03, 5.343e-03, 4.138e-03],
>           [8.565e-03, 1.696e-01, 2.259e...

Comment: Why are the weights input to the model and not just a constant? Do you want to have a different weight per each sample?

Comment: Yes, the weights change per sample.

Comment: Why do you need to have the weights as input tothe model? Can't you pass the weights as a numpy array to weighted_mse function?

Comment: Also, what is nbin? I see you are using it at multiple different parts and do not get what this variable is.

Comment: nbin is a numpy scalar